# How to count the number of matches and use it inside of a regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get this result:

```
<li class="beatle_1">Paul</li> <li class="beatle_2">John</li> <li class="beatle_3">George</li> <li class="beatle_4">Ringo</li>
```

From this regular expression in PHP:

```
echo preg_replace('/([\w]+)/','<li class="beatle_$n">\1</li>','Paul John George Ringo');
```

But I don't know if it is possible to return the number of matches from inside the regular expression.

I have found something about this on a [Perl list](http://www.webmasterkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/perl/4077/regex-pcre-variable-number-of-captures-how):

Janet: "You could put the first result into a variable, then add (concatenate) other results to it after each capture.  This also keeps you from depending on $1 (or whatever) later in the program, when it may be rewritten by another regex use."

And Bob Walton:

```
my $input='a b c d e';
my @output=$input=~/(\w)\s*/g;
print join "\n",@output;
```

And Jörg Westheide: "That's right, lib pcre doesn't have that. And I also have not (yet) found a way to implement the g modifier in a full Perl compatible way. For details on the problematic stuff see the 'Repeated patterns matching zero-length substring' section in the perlre man page. If that doesn't apply to your problem you should be able to solve your problem with a loop."

Comment: This seems like a terrible abuse of regular expressions. Why *must* this be done with regex?

Comment: you can get the matched results by doing preg_match and preg_match_all go here for more information http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php. but again your complicating things here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PHP5.3 you can use anonymous function for this.

See this example

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/([\w]+)/', function ($matches) {
    static $pos = 0;
    return sprintf('<li class="beatle_%d">%s</li>', ++$pos, $matches[1]);
}, 'Paul John George Ringo');
```

Comment: Or, prior to 5.3, you can just use `preg_replace_callback` with a regular function.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in python? (capture the number of times a matching group repeated with a '*' operator)???

Answer (score 0):

You could try `preg_replace_callback()` with a closure if you're using PHP 5.3:

```
$subject = 'Paul John George Ringo';
$n = 0;
echo preg_replace_callback('/([\w]+)/', function($matches) use (&$n) {
    return '<li class="beatle_'.(++$n).'">'.$matches[1].'</li>';
}, $subject);
```

Comment: Sorry, you code is returning: <li class="beatle_0">Paul</li> <li class="beatle_0">John</li> <li class="beatle_0">George</li> <li class="beatle_0">Ringo</li> By the way, I am using: PHP 5.3.5 (cli) (built: Jan  7 2011 18:14:45), Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group, Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies

Comment: Did you make sure to use: `use (&$n)`? (notice the reference). I get the expected result: "<li class="beatle_1">Paul</li> <li class="beatle_2">John</li> <li class="beatle_3">George</li> <li class="beatle_4">Ringo</li>" on PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Sep 28 2010 13:38:04) Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies